# angular AG Grid ICellRendererAngularComp not found

Tags: angular, typescript, cellrenderer

Ive just started using AG Grid and Im having a problem with the demos

** see link below

the example references ICellRendererAngularComp which it says is located in

ag-grid-community/angular

but I cant find it.  Heres the typescript code, can anyone shed any light on this ?  Ive got the grid installed correctly on my system (Angular 11) but I cant figure out where this comp is

```
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'medal-component',
  template: `<span>{{ this.displayValue }}</span>`,
})
export class MedalCellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public displayValue!: string;

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams<IOlympicData, number>): void {
    this.displayValue = new Array(params.value).fill('#').join('');
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I get an error 'Module ag-grid-community has no exported member ICellRendererAngularComp'
and @ag-grid-community/angular doesnt exist  only @ag-grid-community exists

looks like the plunket link doesnt work, Ive accessed the samples from this url

[AG Grid samples](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#example-simple)

Comment: I think the link you provided is broken (?)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, Ive added the actual samples page, looks like the plunket url doesnt point to the correct place

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to solve this myself.  Im using the legacy version of ag-grid, so the import should be this

```
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular-legacy';
```

im using angular 11 so I have to use the legacy version, angular 12 and up uses the standard angular grid